# Best datatype to store a number (0-999) in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to store the number of products each warehouse has which will be between 0-999 and I am not sure which is the best datatype for my case.

I was thinking of using SMALLINT(3) but I'd like some feedback if possible.

Comment: The max values for int data types can be found here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html. In my experience 0-999 will blow fairly quickly int may be more appropriate for future proofing.

Comment: *"I was thinking of using SMALLINT(3) but I'd like some feedback if possible."* `SMALLINT(3)` does not store a max three width length numbers .. so `SMALLINT(3)` does not store a max of `999` to make one thing clear

Comment: @Raymond Nijland - the width length option does not change the minimum or maximum of stored values. so SMALLINT(1) and SMALLINT(3) is the same size

Comment: @Raymond Nijland - my misatake - sorry Bernd

Comment: *"the width length option does not change the minimum or maximum of stored values. so SMALLINT(1) and SMALLINT(3) is the same size "* if you read the comments  @BerndBuffen you would understand iám well aware of that.. the `(<number>)` part is meant for MySQL's zerofill option..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Hmm then I don't really get the point of the number :/ Thank you for the info though

Comment: @George - If in doubt - take BIGINT UNSIGNED. I mean.. you either know what you need, or you don't.

Comment: @George the number in `SMALLINT(3)` is meant to be used in combination with MySQL's [zerofill](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/numeric-type-attributes.html) .. Also i advice never to use the Zerofill option.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Ok mate thank you very much. So I better just store it without a length number. Because until now I was adding that number because I thought it would limit the total amount of numbers I could store..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, because the range for smallint is between -32.768 and +32.767.

Answer (score 0):

based on your requirement you can use signed int or unsign int

> INT(length)   Integer with a range from –2147483648 to +2147483647. The
>   number that can be displayed is limited by length. For example, if
>   length is 4, only numbers from –999 to 9999 can be displayed, even
>   though higher numbers are stored.
>
> INT(length) UNSIGNED  Integer with a range from 0 to 4294967295. length
>   is the size of the number that can be displayed. For example, if
>   length is 4, only numbers from 0 to 9999 can be displayed, even though
>   higher numbers are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Since TINYINT cannot accommodate value beyond 255, then SMALLINT is the next option. I will suggest SMALLINT(4) to be on save side.

Comment: Why is `SMALLINT(4)` more safer then `SMALLINT(3)` or `SMALLINT` ? `SMALLINT(3)` does not store a max three width length numbers .. so `SMALLINT(3)` does not store a max of `999`  and `SMALLINT(4)` does not have a max of `9999` to make one thing clear